# 'SMOTE' not found in R

Tags: r

I was trying to handle unbalance in the target variable in my logistic regression problem in R. I used SMOTE for this. However, it keeps showing "ERROR: Function SMOTE not found" even though I've installed the required package DMwR. The target column is TenYearHD.

"
Error in SMOT(TenYearCHD ~ ., trainData, perc.over = 400, k = 5, perc.under = 100) :
could not find function "SMOT
"

Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: `SMOTE` or `SMOT`? Your error message is inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

Did you load the `DMwR` library first? Then, check your function call. In your post, you are trying to call the function `SMOT`, not `SMOTE`.

```
library(DMwR)
SMOTE(TenYearCHD ~ ., trainData, perc.over = 400, k = 5, perc.under = 100)
```